# How to correctly stop CSS Grid Columns from expanding

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I know there is a lot of documentation to this but I've only managed to find one working solution. I have a grid with 1 row and 3 columns. The first column has a lot of text that makes the column automatically expand to fit it. Code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <h1>dummytextdummytextdummytext</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the columns still automatically expand to fit the "dummytext" `h1`.
Now, when I specifically apply a class, say `column-1` to the specific column that overflows, it stops overflowing and strictly adheres to the size of `1fr`. Example:

```
.column-1
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

My question is, why does it work when I specifically apply it to a column, and how do I get it to apply to the grid as a whole?

Comment: repeat(3,minmax(0,1fr)) instead of 1fr 1fr 1fr

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried what you did, and it did keep the column size to 1fr, but now my text is overflowing. I've kept overflow: hidden as well.